# algorithmicrequire undefined when using algorithmicx

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I was using `algorithmic` and `algorithm` to write algorithm:

```
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input: }}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output: }}
```

and now I need to use `algorithmicx` instead of `algorithmic`, in order to use `\algstore{myalg}`. Since my algorithm is too long to fit in one page.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
```

After I compiled the `Tex` file, I got the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.219 \REQUIRE
```

SO how to resolve the issue?

thanks

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=91176#p91176).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `\Require` instead of `\REQUIRE`. LaTeX is case-sensitive. Here's a small example with `\Require` which I made for my next [LaTeX book](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook), as a demo showing several features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\minbox}[2]{%
  \mathmakebox[\ifdim#1<\width\width\else#1\fi]{#2}}
\newcommand{\Let}[2]{\State $ \minbox{1em}{#1} \gets #2 $}
\algnewcommand{\Local}{\State\textbf{local variables: }}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Mandelbrot set}
  \label{alg:mandelbrot}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{$c_x, c_y, \Sigma_{\max} \in \mathds{R},
      \quad i \in \mathds{N}, \quad i_{\max} > 0,
      \quad \Sigma_{\max} > 0$}
    \Function{mandelbrot}{$c_x, c_y, i_{\max},
              \Sigma_{\max}$}
      \Local{$x, y, x^\prime, y^\prime, i, \Sigma$}
      \Let{x, y, i, \Sigma}{0}
        \Comment{initial zero value for all}
      \While{$\Sigma \leq \Sigma_{\max}$
             and $i < i_{\max}$}
        \Let{x^\prime}{x^2 - y^2 + c_x}
        \Let{y^\prime}{2xy + c_y}
        \Let{m}{x^\prime}
        \Let{y}{y^\prime}
        \Let{\Sigma}{x^2 + y^2}
      \EndWhile
      \If{$i < i_{\max}$}
        \State \Return{$i$}
      \EndIf
      \State\Return{0}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Algorithm]

For completeness, in the [LaTeX-Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/) forum the question was posted in this thread: "[How to continue displaying an algorithm if it is too long](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26584)".

Comment: The code works great. I have 2 questions. 1. How to reference the line numbers in the algorithm, e.g. make a `\label` command just like in `figure`? 2. How to not showing the `end if`, 'end for' etc. They takes a lot lines seems to be unnecessary.